# Javascript Validation clashing with PHP Validation?

Tags: javascript, php

I tried to have a comprehensive look through previously asked questions, but can't seem to find anything that matches my issue.

I'm running a frontend form validator through javascript, just to check for blank inputs, which if the user passes, will populate a table in mysql through php.

I've found I simply cannot run both actions concurrently - either my javascript works and displays my errors, but does not even go near the database, or javascript will just not function at all, and will send form data through to the database even when fields are empty.

Code:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const firstname = document.getElementById('firstname');
const surname = document.getElementById('surname');
const dob = document.getElementById('dob');
const gender = document.getElementById('gender');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const username = document.getElementById('username');
const password = document.getElementById('password');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  checkInputs();
});

function checkInputs() {
  // trim to remove the whitespaces
  const firstnameValue = firstname.value.trim();
  const surnameValue = surname.value.trim();
  const dobValue = dob.value.trim();
  const genderValue = gender.value.trim();
  const emailValue = email.value.trim();
  const usernameValue = username.value.trim();
  const passwordValue = password.value.trim();

  if (firstnameValue === '') {
    setErrorFor(firstname, 'Field cannot be blank');
  } else {
    setSuccessFor(firstname);
  }

  if (surnameValue === '') {
    setErrorFor(surname, 'Field cannot be blank');
  } else {
    setSuccessFor(surname);
  }

  if (dobValue === '') {
    setErrorFor(dob, 'Field cannot be blank');
  } else {
    setSuccessFor(dob);
  }

  if (genderValue === '') {
    setErrorFor(gender, 'Field cannot be blank');
  } else {
    setSuccessFor(gender);
  }

  if (emailValue === '') {
    setErrorFor(email, 'Email cannot be blank');
  } else if (!isEmail(emailValue)) {
    setErrorFor(email, 'Not a valid email');
  } else {
    setSuccessFor(email);
  }

  if (usernameValue === '') {
    setErrorFor(username, 'Field cannot be blank');
  } else {
    setSuccessFor(username);
  }

  if (passwordValue === '') {
    setErrorFor(password, 'Password cannot be blank');
  } else {
    setSuccessFor(password);
  }
}

function setErrorFor(input, message) {
  const formControl = input.parentElement;
  const small = formControl.querySelector('small');
  formControl.className = 'form-control error';
  small.innerText = message;
}

function setSuccessFor(input) {
  const formControl = input.parentElement;
  formControl.className = 'form-control success';
}

function isEmail(email) {
  return /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script defer src="registration.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/553d8c77af.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="register.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="header">
        <h2>New Account Registration</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <form id="form" action="insert.php" name="form" method="POST">
          <div class="form-control">
            <label for="username">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
            <small>Error message</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-control">
            <label for="username">Surname</label>
            <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" />
            <small>Error message</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-control">
            <label for="username">Date of Birth</label>
            <input type="date" name="dob" id="dob" />
            <small>Error message</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-control">
            <label for="username">Please select your Gender:</label>
            <select id="gender" class="input" name="gender">
              <option value="" id="gender">Please choose an option</option>
              <option value="Male" id="gender">Male</option>
              <option value="Female" id="gender">Female</option>
              <option value="Prefer not to Say" id="gender">Prefer not to Say</option>
            </select>
            <small>Error message</small></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-control">
          <label for="username">Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
          <small>Error message</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
          <label for="username">Username</label>
          <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
          <small>Error message</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
          <label for="username">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
          <small>Error message</small>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Form">
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**PHP Insert**

```
<?php
include_once 'db.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{    
     $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
     $surname = $_POST['surname'];
     $dob = $_POST['dob'];
     $gender = $_POST['gender'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];
     $sql = "INSERT INTO members (firstname,surname,dob,gender,email,username,password)
     VALUES ('$firstname','$surname','$dob','$gender','$email','$username','$password')";
     if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "New record has been added successfully !";
     } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . ":-" . mysqli_error($conn);
     }
     mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

**PHP Server Connect**

```
<?php
    $servername='localhost';
    $username='root';
    $password='';
    $dbname = 'healthhubmembers';
    
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,"$dbname");
      if(!$conn){
          die('Could not Connect MySql Server:' .mysqli_error());
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add form.submit() after checking validation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response, but can you elaborate?

Comment: you have used  e.preventDefault(); to disable form default behaviour and then you used checkInputs(); to validate fields. Now you have to submit the form by using form.submit();

Comment: I tried adding it, but think I may be adding it on the wrong spot, can you tell me where to put it? I', only new